# Oracle SQL - Update query with NOT EXISTS does not work

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I think I am going wrong with Oracle SQL syntax. This is the syntax I use in Transact-SQL.

```
UPDATE "DE_OPS"
SET IMPORT_DATE = GETDATE()
WHERE PROCEDURE_CODE NOT IN ( SELECT DISTINCT PROCEDURE_CODE FROM DE_OPS_20140730 );
```

I reframed this for Oracle SQL as

```
UPDATE "DE_OPS"
 SET IMPORT_DATE = SYSDATE()
WHERE PROCEDURE_CODE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT DISTINCT PROCEDURE_CODE FROM DE_OPS_20140730);
```

But this gives the error

Error at Command Line : 3 Column : 26
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:
*Action:

Not sure where I am going wrong. Does "not exists" allow subqueries?

Comment: I hope you are ware that the way you use `NOT EXISTS` changes what the statement does. The first one updates all rows with a *matching*  `procedure_code`. The second one updates all rows if there is at no row `DE_OPS_20140730` at all. Why did you change the `NOT IN` to `NOT EXISTS` in the first place? The syntax error however is unrelated to that: it's `SYSDATE` not `sysdate()`.

Comment: Using the `NOT IN` is fine with Oracle, just use SYSDATE instead of GETDATE()

Comment: In any case, you don't need the `DISTINCT` keyword in your subquery. The outer query will only return one row per value in the `NOT IN` and `NOT EXISTS` subqueries, and including `DISTINCT` only adds overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need of parentheses after sysdate. Try:

```
UPDATE "DE_OPS"
 SET IMPORT_DATE = SYSDATE
WHERE PROCEDURE_CODE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT DISTINCT PROCEDURE_CODE FROM DE_OPS_20140730);
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is *either* NOT EXISTS or NOT IN.  You're mixing the two.

```
UPDATE "DE_OPS"
 SET IMPORT_DATE = SYSDATEECT DISTINCT PROCEDURE_CODE FROM DE_OPS_20140730);
```

OR

```
UPDATE "DE_OPS" d
 SET IMPORT_DATE = SYSDATE
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT DISTINCT PROCEDURE_CODE FROM DE_OPS_20140730 WHERE PROCEDURE_CODE = d.PROCEDURE_CODE);
```